# Match genre IDs with Names - TMDB

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

I have the follwoing arrays of genre ids:

```
$genre_ids = array(28, 12, 80);
```

And I know that 28 indicates Action & 12 indicates Adventure & 16 indicates Animation
I want to turn the above array of genre_ids to genre names

The follwing code does the work but I'm not sure if its a good practice.

```
<?php

$genres = array(
    28 => "Action",
    12 => "Adventure",
    16 => "Animation"
);

$ids = array(28, 12, 80);

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    echo $genres[$id] . "<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Since the genres are managed by the API, I would say that this is a valid way of doing it. I would probably fetch the list of genres from [their API](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/genres/get-movie-list) though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looping through all genre ids, but not all genre ids have genre names, you'll be getting `Notice: Undefined offset` on every ids with no names. This may not be a breaking issue, and you can exclude notices in production logs, but it'll make debugging with logs during dev very difficult due unnecessary (but easily avoidable) notices.

Try checking for key/offset first before referencing them, eg:

```
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    echo isset($genres[$id]) ? "{$genres[$id]}<br>" : '<br>';
    // Or
    echo ($genres[$id] ?? '') . '<br>';
}
```

We can also do it without any loops and ifs/ternary operators, and could be advantageous when we have 100's or more of genres (benchmark to see if worth it):

```
$genres = array(
    28 => "Action",
    12 => "Adventure",
    16 => "Animation",
    ...
);

$ids = array(28, 12, 80, ...);

// Turn the ids into keys so we can perform operations by keys
$keyedIds = array_flip($ids);  // [28 => 0, 12 => 1, 80 => 2, ...];
// Exclude ids that already has genre names
$unnamedIds = array_diff_key($keyedIds, $genres);  // [80 => 2, ...];
// Turn the remaining ids/keys back to values
$unnamedIds = array_flip($unnamedIds);  // [2 => 80, ...];
// Create an array similar to $genres, but for ids with no genre names, with a specified "name"
$defaultNames = array_fill_keys($unnamedIds, 'Unknown genre');  // [80 => 'Unknown genre', ...]

$genres = $genres + unnamedIds;  // [28 => 'Action', 12 => 'Adventure', 80 => 'Unknown genre', ...];
echo implode('<br>', $genres) . '<br>';  // Action<br>Adventure<br>Unknown genre...<br>
```